# Unexpected End of File - Android Layout

Tags: android, xml

I cannot seem to figure out what I left out in my xml, but I am getting "unexpected end of file" on the last line.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Dummy Text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not closed your `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>` element. Add a  `</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>` at the end.